# Contagem em duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, join, count, distinct

Estou com problemas para fazer a contagem de itens referentes aos bairros. Preciso listar todos os bairros da cidade X e mostrar os itens carros e motos disponíveis. No exemplo só usei uma cidade para facilitar a ilustração. Usei `group by` e `left join` mas não fez a contagem correta.

Não sei se o erro é meu, ou se ha uma dificuldade em usar join nesse caso, mas alguma soluções que encontrei sugerem algo como a query abaixo:

<sub>[Ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3761257/1244639)</sub>

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE someCondition) as table1Count, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE someCondition) as table2Count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3 WHERE someCondition) as table3Count
```

<sub>[Ref 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/944128/1244639)</sub>

```
SELECT co.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM modules mod WHERE mod.course_id=co.id) AS moduleCount, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videos vid WHERE vid.course_id=co.id) AS vidCount
FROM courses AS co
ORDER BY co.id DESC
```

As referências acima tornam a condição muito repetitiva. Algum `join` supre essa necessidade?

---

<sub>**tabela**</sub>

```
TBL.BAIRROS
ID | CIDADE | BAIRRO
1  | 1      | Meier
2  | 1      | Copacabana

TBL.CARROS
ID | BAIRRO | MODELO
1  | 1      | Modelo 1
2  | 1      | Modelo 2

TBL.MOTOS
ID | BAIRRO | MODELO
1  | 2      | Modelo 1
```

<sub>**output esperado**</sub>

```
array(
    0 => array
         bairro => Meier
         carros => 2
         motos  => 0

    1 => array
         bairro => Copacabana
         carros => 0
         motos  => 1
)
```

<sub>**usando left join**</sub>

```
...
, count( carros.id ) carros
, count( motos.id  ) motos
from bairros
left join motos  on motos.bairro  = bairros.id
left join carros on carros.bairro = bairros.id
group by bairros.bairro
```

---

### <sub>Update</sub>

Enquanto escrevia achei uma possível solução usando `count( DISTINCT ... )`. O output saiu como esperado, mas queria saber se a solução somente contorna um problema da query ou se é a forma correta.

```
...
, count( DISTINCT carros.id ) carros
, count( DISTINCT motos.id  ) motos
from bairros
left join motos  on motos.bairro  = bairros.id
left join carros on carros.bairro = bairros.id
group by bairros.bairro
```

Comment: Quando vc usa um "left join", vc tem os resultados que são e também os que não são. Para ter somente os "que são" precisa usar "inner join". Precisa ver si, usando "left join" + "distinct" vc não esta criando simplesmente um "tipo de inner join".

Comment: Uma dica quanto aos campos das tabelas. Dê preferencia a usar chaves primarias com o "id" seguido do nome da tabela no singular, pois isso facilita a compreensão do SQL principalmente na hora de fazer `JOINS`.

Answer (score 3):

Tente `JOIN` com `COUNT` definindo o campo que será contado pois ele ignora os registros nulos.

```
SELECT
  bairro,
  COUNT(idCarro) AS qtde_carros,
  COUNT(idMoto) AS qtde_motos
FROM bairro b
  LEFT JOIN carros c ON (c.idBairro = b.idBairro)
  LEFT JOIN motos m ON (m.idBairro = b.idBairro)
GROUP BY bairro
```

Comment: Desculpe minha falta de perspicácia, mas, além de alterar `GROUP BY bairro`, o que mais há de diferente da minha query? Queria entender a alteração entes de rodar. Obrigado.

Comment: Na verdade nenhuma, pois quando respondi ainda não tinha visto o "UPDATE" da pergunta. O DISTINCT no COUNT vai "dizer" ao mesmo que só deve considerar os diferentes. Se você fizer um COUNT por modelo de moto e tiver duas motos do mesmo modelo no mesmo bairro ele só vai retornar 1, porem sem o DISTINCT ele retornaria 2.